# SQL DECODE optimisation

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

If I use something like this inside an UPDATE instruction and I want to check if the functions returns 'N', so set ' ':

```
ta.COD_ACT_MCH= ALIMENTATION_COD_ACT_MCH(ta.CA_DDE_TYP_DDE,tb.COD_SECVTE,tb.NUM_FOU1,ta.CA_COD_ENSCIAL)
```

is this the way to do it? or it calls the function twice? How can I optimize this?

```
   ta.COD_ACT_MCH=DECODE( ALIMENTATION_COD_ACT_MCH(ta.CA_DDE_TYP_DDE,tb.COD_SECVTE,tb.NUM_FOU1,ta.CA_COD_ENSCIAL),
'N',
' ',
ALIMENTATION_COD_ACT_MCH(ta.CA_DDE_TYP_DDE,tb.COD_SECVTE,tb.NUM_FOU1,ta.CA_COD_ENSCIAL))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **hack** will work unless `ALIMENTATION_COD_ACT_MCH` can return `NULL`:

```
NVL(NULLIF(
  ALIMENTATION_COD_ACT_MCH(ta.CA_DDE_TYP_DDE,tb.COD_SECVTE,tb.NUM_FOU1,ta.CA_COD_ENSCIAL),
  'N'), '')
```

Comment: In Oracle, an empty string evaluates to null, so your `NVL(whatever,'')` is futile.

Answer (score 1):

Add DETERMINISTIC/RESULT CACHE clause to you function ALIMENTATION_COD_ACT_MCH. So it would be possible to use it twice or more in select list, but oracle would be calculate result of function only once.

Comment: Only add `DETERMINISTIC` if the function really is deterministic. If it's not (e.g. if it's looking up a value in a table) you may get incorrect results.